# CentOS on Virtualbox, have to use ifdown/ifup after startup

Tags: networking, centos, virtualbox

I installed CentOS 7 on a virtual machine, using Virtualbox.  I added a host-only interface to the machine before installing the OS, so I can access it from my host environment.  In installed `net-tools` using `yum`.

Everything works fine, except that I have to run the following commands everytime I start the machine.  After startup, the corresponding interface has no IP, so I cannot access the machine from my host:

```
sudo ifdown enp0s8
sudo ifup enp0s8
```

Only after those commands, my virtual machine gets the IP `192.198.56.101`, so I can connect through SSH from my host.

Is it the symptom I did something wrong?  Should I/can I change something in Virtualbox or CentOS to make the interface up when I startup the machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [CentOS 7 FAQ](http://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/CentOS7), network interfaces aren't enabled by default for some reason.

You can change this behavior by modifying `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s8`(for interface enp0s8). Just change `ONBOOT=no` to `ONBOOT=yes`

Comment: I missed this somehow.  This solves the problem perfectly!  Thank you!